# Recursive VBA Precedents

Tags: vba, excel, recursion

I have an excel spreadsheet with quite a few formulas and data that I keep track of.  I have a small macro that will find the Precedents for a selected cell however id like to make the macro recursive so that I can find all of the precedents. Eg Setting focus to a cell and running this function will highlight the cell and then highlight the precedents of the cell, then highlight the precedents of those cells, then highlight the precedents...

The problem I am having at the moment is I am not sure what the escape condition should be.  I have ran into a few infinite loop problems and am not familiar with recursion enough to figure out a solid solution.

Below is some code that I am using to (correctly) find the inital precedents:

```
Sub FindClosedWbReferences(inRange As Range)
Rem fills the collection With closed precedents parsed from the formula String
Dim testString As String, returnStr As String, remnantStr As String
testString = inRange.Formula
testString = RemoveTextInDoubleQuotes(testString): Rem New line
Set ClosedWbRefs = New Collection
Do
    returnStr = NextClosedWbRefStr(testString, remnantStr)
    ClosedWbRefs.Add Item:=returnStr, Key:=CStr(ClosedWbRefs.count)
    testString = remnantStr
    inRange.Select
    inRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 36

Loop Until returnStr = vbNullString

ClosedWbRefs.Remove ClosedWbRefs.count
End Sub
```

and this is called from a main function that looks similar to:

```
 If homeCell.HasFormula Then
    Set OtherWbRefs = New Collection: CountOfClosedWb = 0
    Set SameWbOtherSheetRefs = New Collection
    Set SameWbSameSheetRefs = New Collection

    Rem find closed precedents from formula String
    Call FindClosedWbReferences(homeCell)
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: +1 for good question, with code sample. Unfortunately I'm not able to assist.

Comment: What specifically are you hoping that we can provide?  It's not apparent what the problem is.

Comment: The range object already has a `Precedents` property that returns the list of precedents. It is not clear what else you are trying to accomplish from your incomplete code listing.

Comment: At the moment the code will take the ActiveCell's Precedents and change their color so that I can easily identify them.  What i'd like is after this occurs, to take the precedents that the original activecell produced and then find the precedents for those precedents. I assumed recursion would be the best way to solve this.

Comment: What you are trying to do is really hard. Maybe it's worth buying [this](http://www.jkp-ads.com/RefTreeAnalyser.asp).

Comment: @DougGlancy: If I am not wrong then you have to manually "Do Active Cell" each time to find further precedents. It won't automatically show the complete tree.

Comment: @Jingles177: I can show you an example of complete looping for precedents in the same sheet. Would that help?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comments above, here is an example which will work for precedents in the same sheet. This will give you a start for finding precedents in other sheets as well.

Let's say, our Excel File looks like this (*Sample File link mentioned in the end*).

[image]

```
Cell A6 has the formula : =B6
Cell B6 has the formula : =C5+C7
Cell C5 has the formula : =D3+D4+D5
Cell C7 has the formula : =D7+D8+D9
'
' And so on. Cells, D4, D5, D8, D9, F3, G3, F9
' G9, G4:I4, G10:I10 do not have any formulas
```

I picked up the code from [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17028&p=86877#post86877) and modified it further to suit my needs.

See this code

```
Dim rw As Long, col As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fRange As Range

Sub Sample()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Clear cell for output
    ws.Rows("20:" & ws.Rows.Count).Clear

    '~~> Select First Cell
    Set fRange = ws.Range("A6")

    '~~> Set Row for Writing
    rw = 20

    FindPrecedents fRange
End Sub

Sub FindPrecedents(Rng As Range)
    ' written by Bill Manville
    ' With edits from PaulS
    ' With further edits by Me 14 Sept 2013
    ' this procedure finds the cells which are the direct precedents of the active cell
    Dim rLast As Range, iLinkNum As Integer, iArrowNum As Integer
    Dim stMsg As String
    Dim bNewArrow As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rng.ShowPrecedents
    Set rLast = Rng
    iArrowNum = 1
    iLinkNum = 1
    bNewArrow = True

    col = 1

    ws.Cells(rw, col).Value = Rng.Address

    col = col + 1

    Do
        Do
            Application.Goto rLast

            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveCell.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=True, ArrowNumber:=iArrowNum, LinkNumber:=iLinkNum
            If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0

            If rLast.Address(external:=True) = ActiveCell.Address(external:=True) Then Exit Do

            bNewArrow = False

            ws.Cells(rw, col).Value = Selection.Address
            col = col + 1

            iLinkNum = iLinkNum + 1  ' try another link
        Loop

        If bNewArrow Then Exit Do

        iLinkNum = 1: bNewArrow = True
        iArrowNum = iArrowNum + 1  'try another arrow
    Loop

    rLast.Parent.ClearArrows
    Application.Goto rLast

    '~~> Write Output
    If Len(Trim(ws.Cells(rw, 2).Value)) <> 0 Then
        With ws
            '~~> Find Last column in that row
            lcol = .Cells(rw, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            j = rw + 1

            For i = 2 To lcol
                .Cells(j, 1).Value = .Cells(rw, i)
                j = j + 1
            Next i
        End With
    End If

    rw = rw + 1

    '~~> Here is where I am looping again
    If Len(Trim(ws.Cells(rw, 1).Value)) <> 0 Then
        FindPrecedents Range(ws.Cells(rw, 1).Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

**Sample File**

You can download the sample file from [HERE](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=CDD3F8ABE20BBE3B!218&authkey=!AFNKljVouPBN1do) to tinker with. Run the macro `Sheet1.Sample()`

If you want you can create further precedents for G4:I4, G10:I10 and test it :)