# Trace back missing reference cell (Find precedents)

Tags: vba, excel, reference

**INTRODUCTION**

I have a spreadsheet with formulas read by a VBA macro. At times, those formulas link to cells that lost references. (The relation tree can go up an undefined number of levels)

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

What I would like to achieve is that whenever this happens, the code returns to the user a message box with the original rogue cell position. (Trace the error back to the origin).

Main difficulty I am facing is following proper branch to the origin of the error.

**EXAMPLE**

One workbook with two worksheets with following formulas:

- Cell `Sheet1!A1` = `=IF(#REF!="", "", B2)` (Someone replaced the original cell content and now the reference is lost)
- Cell `Sheet1!B1` = `=A1`
- Cell `Sheet1!B2` = `=11`
- Cell `Sheet2!A1` = `=12`
- Cell `Sheet2!B1` = `=A1+Sheet1!A1+Sheet1!B1`

I am interested in tracing back `Sheet2!B1` to its original reference error.

And code tried so far:

```
Sub CheckRangeB1()
    Dim RangeB1 As Range
    Dim RogueAddress As String
    Set RangeB1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")

    RogueAddress = MissingRef(RangeB1)
    MsgBox RogueAddress
End Sub

Public Function MissingRef(ByVal CheckRange As Range) As String
    Dim RogueCell As Range
    If IsError(CheckRange) Then
        If CheckRange.Value = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then
            If HasPrecedents(CheckRange) = False Then
                MissingRef = CheckRange.Address
            ElseIf IsError(CheckRange.DirectPrecedents) Then
                MissingRef = MissingRef(CheckRange.DirectPrecedents)
            Else
                MissingRef = CheckRange.Address
            End If
        End If
    Else
        MissingRef = "NOERROR"
    End If
End Function

Public Function HasPrecedents(ByVal target As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    HasPrecedents = target.DirectPrecedents.Count
End Function
```

Which at the moment is quite useless because `.DirectPrecedents` is only tracing back `Sheet2!A1`.

**EDIT**

Another approach may be parsing the formula and following the referenced cells. But I am not sure how to extract the referenced cells not knowing beforehand how does the formula look. I would still prefer the `.DirectPrecedents`
approach.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it although it was harder than it looked like at the beginning.

The attached code traces back the original cell with the missing reference but just the first one it finds. (i.e. if there are two cells with missing references it will return the first one only)

It should work with any case missing a reference.

Taking bits of code found over the internet and mainly following this lead [Recursive VBA Precedents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795573/recursive-vba-precedents/18798347#18798347) pointed by @siddharth-rout I got to:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CheckRangeB1()
    Dim RangeB1 As Range, PrecedentsRange As Range
    Dim RogueAddress As String
    Set RangeB1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")

    Dim PrecedentsString As Variant
    RogueAddress = MissingRef(RangeB1)
    MsgBox RogueAddress
End Sub

Public Function MissingRef(ByVal CheckRange As Range) As String
    Dim RogueCell As Range
    Dim PrecedString() As String
    Dim returnString As String
    Dim ErrorCheck As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, UpperBound As Long
    If IsError(CheckRange) Then
        If CheckRange.Value = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then
            UpperBound = UBound(FindPrecedents(CheckRange))
            ReDim PrecedString(UpperBound)
            PrecedString = FindPrecedents(CheckRange)
            If UpperBound = 0 And PrecedString(0) = "" Then
                MissingRef = "'" & CheckRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & CheckRange.Address
            Else
                ErrorCheck = False
                For i = 1 To UBound(PrecedString)
                    If IsError(Range(PrecedString(i))) Then
                        ErrorCheck = True
                        MissingRef = MissingRef(Range(PrecedString(i)))
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                If ErrorCheck = False Then
                    MissingRef = "'" & CheckRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & CheckRange.Address
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Else
        MissingRef = "NOERROR"
    End If
End Function

Function FindPrecedents(ByVal Rng As Range) As Variant
    ' written by Bill Manville
    ' With edits from PaulS
    ' Further edited by LG
    ' this procedure finds the cells which are the direct precedents of the active cell
    Dim ReturnRng() As String
    Dim rLast As Range, iLinkNum As Integer, iArrowNum As Integer
    Dim stMsg As String
    Dim bNewArrow As Boolean
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rng.ShowPrecedents
    Set rLast = Rng
    iArrowNum = 1
    iLinkNum = 1
    bNewArrow = True
    Do
        Do
            Application.Goto rLast
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveCell.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=True, ArrowNumber:=iArrowNum, LinkNumber:=iLinkNum
            If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
            If rLast.Address(external:=True) = ActiveCell.Address(external:=True) Then Exit Do
            bNewArrow = False
            If rLast.Worksheet.Parent.Name = ActiveCell.Worksheet.Parent.Name Then
                If rLast.Worksheet.Name = ActiveCell.Parent.Name Then
                    ' local
                    stMsg = stMsg & ";" & Selection.Address
                Else
                    stMsg = stMsg & ";" & "'" & Selection.Parent.Name & "'!" & Selection.Address
                End If
            Else
                ' external
                stMsg = stMsg & ";" & Selection.Address(external:=True)
            End If
            iLinkNum = iLinkNum + 1  ' try another link
        Loop
        If bNewArrow Then Exit Do
        iLinkNum = 1
        bNewArrow = True
        iArrowNum = iArrowNum + 1  'try another arrow
    Loop
    rLast.Parent.ClearArrows
    Application.Goto rLast

    If stMsg = "" Then
        ReDim ReturnRng(0)
        ReturnRng(0) = ""
    Else
        ReDim ReturnRng(0 To UBound(Split(stMsg, ";")))
        ReturnRng = Split(stMsg, ";")
    End If

    FindPrecedents = ReturnRng()

    'Exit Function
End Function
```

Hope someone finds it usefull!

**EDIT**

When I tried to generalise the code I found an error due to the use of `.DirectPrecedents` which doesn't trace back references properly from worksheet to worksheet. I droped it an fixed the code.